# Use JSON key in Backbone click event

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

My template is displaying correctly.

I want to put a click event on each template.  The click function needs to use a JSON key, but I don't know how to access that.

Template:

```
        <script id="lib-list-item-template" type="text/template">
          <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item lib-list-item">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><%= library_name %></h4>
                <p class="list-group-item-text"><%= street_address %></p>
                <p class="list-group-item-text"><%= city %>, <%= state %> <%= zip %></p>
                <p class="list-group-item-text"><%= phone_number %></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </script>
```

Backbone:

> $(document).ready(function() {
>
> ```
> var Library = Backbone.Model.extend({
> });
>
> var LibraryList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
>   model: Library,
>   url: 'hours.json'
> });
>
> var LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({
>   el: '#libs',
>   template: _.template($('#lib-list-item-template').html()),
>   collection: libraries,
>   events: {
>     "click .lib-list-item": "activate",
>   },
>   activate: function(event) {
>   },
>   render: function(event) {
>
>     _.each(this.model.models, function(library) {
>       var libraryTemplate = this.template(library.toJSON());
>       $(this.el).append(libraryTemplate);
>     }, this);
>
>     return this;
>   }
> });
>
> var libraries = new LibraryList();
> var librariesView = new LibraryView({model: libraries});
>
> libraries.fetch({
>   dataType: 'json',
>   success: function() {
>     librariesView.render();
>   }
> });
> ```

In my `activate` click function in View, how do I access the `myID` JSON key?

> ```
>   activate: function(event) {
>        //I've tried <%= myID %> 
>        console.log(something);
>   },
> ```

Comment: What is the `myID` JSON key? Do you mean the id of each model in the collection?

Comment: `myID` is a key in `hours.json`

Comment: in each Library object

Comment: Your HTML template seems incomplete. It's missing the <a>'s opening tag.

Comment: @PatrickM Fixed, I removed some parts for clarity and I missed that tag.  The HTML template works fine

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way from where you are would be to put the id in a `data-id` attribute in the template (not sure about the exact syntax of your `<a>` since it's missing from question):

```
<a class="lib-list-item" data-id="<%= myID%>"></a>
```

Then, do something like this from the activate handler:

```
activate: function(event) {
    // Pick the id from the data-id attribute of the clicked element.
    var myID = $(event.currentTarget).data('id');
    console.log(myID);
}
```

Comment: `event.currentTarget` is usually a better choice in a delegation environment.

Comment: Sorry, added the `<a>` tag back in.  What would I do for multiple keys?  I'm a beginner with Backbone.js, but to me it seems weird that the flow is Backbone -> HTML template -> Backbone instead of just Backbone

Comment: The full solution would be to have a LibraryList View encompassing the entire list, and multiple instances of a LibraryItem View, used to render each element of the list. The activate function should be defined on LibraryItem View as well as the events attribute. Each LibraryItem View holds a reference to its Model (instance of Library), and can thus access the id using this.model.get('myID');

Comment: As an aside, you could map your myID attribute to Backbone's smart id attribute by using the [idAttribute](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute) configuration. This would allow using `this.model.id` instead of `this.model.get('myID')`.